# How to deal with complex API responses for making cards in Flutter?

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I am very new to Flutter and now developing an app that lists restaurants.
I have an API endpoint that returns JSON data. Here it is: https://node.coredes.in/restaurants.

I have already done the layouts. But I don't know how to deal with JSON data. I already tried to do this from examples I got from net.

I want to know how can I use these fields - doc.name, doc.image_gallery[0], doc.location.locality, doc.friday.closing_at.hour, doc.friday.closing_at.minute, to make a list of cards?

Could anyone please help me out with a sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code below, shows how to get the name of restaurants in your JSON file:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new HomePage(),
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String url = "https://node.coredes.in/restaurants/";
  List data;

  /*onCreate*/
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    getJSONData(); //method
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("my JSON app")),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        // itemCount: 1,
        //itemCount: data==null ? 0 :data.length ,
        itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,

        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new Container(
            child: new Center(
              child: new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Card(
                    child: new Container(
                      child: new Text(data[index]['name'] ?? ''),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  /*method*/ //RT is Future<String>
  Future<String> getJSONData() async {
    var response = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    print(response.body);
    debugPrint(response.body);

    setState(() {
      var convertDataToJson = json.decode(response.body);
      data = convertDataToJson['doc'];
    });

    return "Success";
  }
}
```

And you can play with `data[index]['name']`. For example if you want the city you can do something like that `data[index]['location']['city']`.

So the class model you said, is in order to make your code easy to understand and fast to be reused. Your `JSON` file have a complex embedded data on it, and it's a little difficult to access this data. So using a class model will be very helpful to get easily, whatever the value you want from it. Let me show you that with a concret example, to know when a restaurant will open and close, you need to go along with this hierarchy `doc => opening_times => Sunday => opening_at` and the same for the closing time. So let's translate it to our flutter code, if we want to get just the `hour` value, it will be like `data[index]['opening_time']['Sunday']['opening_at']['hour']`, and the same for `minute` value, same for all the rest. In this hierarchy we didn't took so long to arrive to the end, but you're free to imagine in a very big hierarchy, how it will be the situation. Let's return to our case, now let's take the same example and try to use, like you said, a class model instead of a hard coded `JSON` attributs. Let's write a model class for `Restaurant`.

```
class Restaurant {
  String name;
  String city;
  String day;
  bool isOpen;
  int hourOpen;
  int minuteOpen;
// ..
// ..
// The rest of your wanted attributs
  Restaurant(
      {this.name,
      this.city,
      this.day,
      this.isOpen,
      this.hourOpen,
      this.minuteOpen});
}
```

After that, we will write a method, its main goal is to fill our restaurants variable.

```
  Future<String> getRestaurants() async {
    var response = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    var convertDataToJson = json.decode(response.body);
    data = convertDataToJson['doc'];
    List tempRestaurants = new List();
    data.forEach((restaurant) => {
          tempRestaurants.add(new Restaurant(
              name: restaurant['name'],
              city: restaurant['location']['city'],
              day: 'Sunday',
              isOpen: restaurant['opening_times']['Sunday']['is_open_today'],
              hourOpen: restaurant['opening_times']['Sunday']['opening_at']
                  ['hour'],
              minuteOpen: restaurant['opening_times']['Sunday']['opening_at']
                  ['minute'])),
        });

    setState(() {
      this.restaurants = tempRestaurants;
    });
  }
```

Here is how we get data after writing the model.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("my JSON app")),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: restaurants == null ? 0 : restaurants.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new Container(
            child: new Center(
              child: new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Card(
                    child: new Container(
                      child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text("Name: ${restaurants[index].name}"),
                            Text("City: ${restaurants[index].city}"),
                            Text("Day: ${restaurants[index].day}"),
                            Text("IsOpen: ${restaurants[index].isOpen}"),
                            Text(
                                "Time: ${restaurants[index].hourOpen}:${restaurants[index].minuteOpen}"),
                          ]),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

PS: in this example, I just took `Sunday` value in every restaurant instance, so that I can show you how easily the access to data has become. But you can create a class model for it, let's say `RestaurantDay`, and have attributs like `dayName`, `hourOpen`, `minuteOpen`... And after that, you can link it with the logic where we get data.

Comment: Thank you very much @Moujabr. It works as I expected it to be. But what I am not clear of is, in all the tutorials I saw, they were using separate class for the data. Like, 

class Restaurant {
  String name;
  String imagePath;
  int discountType;
  double rating;
  String opensAt;
  List<String> cuisines;
  String address;

  Restaurant(
      {this.name,
      this.imagePath,
      this.discountType,
      this.rating,
      this.opensAt,
      this.cuisines,
      this.address});
}

Could you explain why, and how to do this?

Comment: That was so nice of you. Any starter can understand what it is. I was really confused, and you saved me.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Moujabr, once more, please. How can I access the openingTimes object inside the forEach loop? That is not part of 'doc' object. I tried this List openingDetails = convertDataToJson['openingDetails']; outside the loop, which cannot be accessed inside the loop.

Comment: You can do exacly like what you have done with `data` variable. First add  `List openingDetails` after `List data`, and then, in the `getRestaurants()` function, add `openingDetails = convertDataToJson['openingDetails']` after `data = convertDataToJson['doc']`. Doing all that, you will able to do what you want. You can test inside the forEach loop with this `print("${openingDetails[index]['id']}")` to see the result in the log .

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class DemoClass {
  String name;
  int Id;

  DemoClass(this.name, this.Id);

  static DemoClass fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DemoClass(json['name'] as String, json['Id'] as int);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(DemoClass instance) =>
    <String, dynamic>{
      'name': instance.name,
      'Id': instance.trackerId
    };

  static List<DemoClass> fromJsonListStr(String jsonStr){
    var list = jsonDecode(jsonStr) as List;
    List<DemoClass> myThing = list.map((e) => DemoClass.fromJson(e)).toList();
    return myThing;
  }
}
```

Use this to get a list of objects:

```
var resp = await http.get('http://apicall.com/array',
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
  var ret = DemoClass.fromJsonListStr(resp.body);
  return ret;
```

Use this to get a single object:

```
var resp = await http.get('http://apicall.com/array',
  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
var data = jsonDecode(resp.body);
var obj = DemoClass.fromJson(data);
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time. But as I am new to Flutter, I couldn't understand how to implement this in my code.

Comment: Hi @Tom, 
I've added logic to show how to make the http get call the the api. I hope this helps.